# Android action from Url

Tags: android, url, android-activity, android-c2dm

I try to start action with service (or activity) from an url. (with params)

Actualy i have a solution to use AlarmManager and call every five minutes the server for test if i must make an action. But it's not immediate and use many battery !)

Is there a solution to directly call an action from a url without using AlarmManager? (for an immediate effect)

I have look C2DM (Android Cloud to Device Messaging Framework) but if a lot of user use this option i think google doesn't like that. (And i prefer use my solution ;) )

Many thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would be better to use a direct push framework, like [mosquitto](http://mosquitto.org/)
Alarm manager doesn't seem like a good idea if you want to do it every 5 mins (I could be wrong)